# How to choose what type of server to use when creating an online multiplayer game?

Tags: multiplayer, online, udp, pong, scala

I want to develop an online multiplayer game using the Scala language. I am quite new to programming; I have developed some simple multiplayer games (think snake, pong), but they cannot be played online. How do I decide what kind of server to use?

Comment: The kind of server depends on what kind of service you plan to offer. You want to allow friends to play on a local wifi multiplayer against each other? One device can be host/ server. Async turn based board game has a different need than a fps game. Handling 500 users in the same scene is different from having 5 (even wow servers crashed at the start when enough people showed up at the same place - GW2 GvGvG at the start was unplayable - Poe was/ is long time struggling with rubber anding - and those are all big name companies)

Comment: @Zibelas the user mentions they're thinking of Pong/Snake, so I think based on those examples we can assume low player count, realtime, with twitch action being significant (i.e. in both these games, a delay in input of just a single frame can be the difference between success and failure).